# What is the easiest way to track local variables in python?

Tags: python, tracking, local-variables

I have train function with so many variables. How can I simply tracks these variables values or some of them in each epoch during training.
The function is look like this:

```
def train_fn(cfgs: TotalConfigs, model_name: str, model: nn.Module, matcher: HungarianMatcher, train_loader, valid_loader, device):
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=cfgs.train.learning_rate) # , weight_decay=cfgs.train.weight_decay
    lr_scheduler = optim.lr_scheduler.CosineAnnealingLR(optimizer, cfgs.train.max_epochs, eta_min=0, last_epoch=-1)
    language_loss = LanguageModelCriterion()
    soft_loss = SoftCriterion()
    cos_loss = CosineCriterion()
    language_loss.to(device)
    best_score, cnt = None, 0
    loss_store, loss_entity, loss_predicate, loss_sentence, loss_xe, loss_soft_target = [], [], [], [], [], []

    with open(cfgs.data.idx2word_path, 'rb') as f:
        idx2word = pickle.load(f)
    with open(cfgs.data.vid2groundtruth_path, 'rb') as f:
        vid2groundtruth = pickle.load(f)

    print('===================Training begin====================')
    print(cfgs.train.save_checkpoints_path)
    for epoch in range(cfgs.train.max_epochs):
        print('\n{}[EPOCH {}]{}'.format('='*15, epoch, '='*15))

        for i, (feature2ds, feature3ds, objects, object_masks, vp_semantics, caption_semantics, numeric_caps, masks, captions, nouns, vids, vocab_ids, vocab_probs, fillmasks) in enumerate(train_loader):
            cnt += 1
            feature2ds = feature2ds.to(device)
            feature3ds = feature3ds.to(device)
            objects = objects.to(device)
            object_masks = object_masks.to(device)
            vp_semantics = vp_semantics.to(device)
            caption_semantics = caption_semantics.to(device)
            numeric_caps = numeric_caps.to(device)
            masks = masks.to(device)
            vocab_ids = vocab_ids.to(device) if vocab_ids is not None else None
            

        

       . . .
```